# In process hsqldb error only when debugging the code

Tags: java, debugging, hsqldb

I'm running in process hsqldb in my java code for testing purposus, and i'm getting the following error:

> user lacks privilege or object not found: MY_TEMP_TABLE

only when i debug the code. If i run the (junit) test without debug, everything is working.
I do need the debugger for some other areas.
I'm getting the error on this query:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TEMP_TABLE VALUES ('a','a','a')
```

I don't think the problem is in sql syntax because all queries are working when running the test without debug.
Any help would be appriciated..

Comment: Is it possible that you use a reserved keyword? : http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/lists-app.html

Comment: @ambiorix , No, i already checked this, i'm using very specific name..

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your table is not present when you debug your code.

One possibility is the table is not created at all. To see what is happening, use the `jdbc:hsqldb:file:yourdb` as the database URL and check the `yourdb.log` file for the CREATE TABLE statements.

The other possibility is the table is not in the PUBLIC (or default) schema and you are not changing the schema to the one that contains the table.